# How to convert QueryString to a Model with Mvc4 not via controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding, request.querystring

I would like to imitate after the controller binding process and bind the query string into a model but **not** via controller.

I have access to `Request.QueryString` from type `NameValueCollection`.
How can i force it to get bind the same as mvc4 binding the models via the controller.

For example i have this class:

```
public class Example
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

and `NameValueCollection(Request.QueryString)` that created by the Request object from the url that is look like `?Name=James&Lastname=Bow`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an ActionFilter then override the OnActionExecuted method. ActionExecutedContext would have access to Request.QueryString. You can then populate the filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model from the query string.

Comment: Because it's not an action in a controller.
I need it out of the controller context that get some url querystring and convert it to a model.
It must be a way to do that like mvc does.

Comment: You said "it's not an action in a controller", then how do you execute the url route (must contain an Action) with the query string? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Assume that it's controller that get only id parameter. And not allowed to get the model as Parameter.
How can i bind it anyway from the url querystring.